# Display a tooltip for two points with exactly the same time

Tags: highcharts

I need to display charts that may contain two different points with exactly the same time on a time axis. In this case Highcharts displays a tooltip for the first point only. Is it possible to have Highcharts display a tooltips for each point?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lod5jsz8/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Snow depth (m)'
            },
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m',
            shared: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Winter 2007-2008',            
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.8 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.2 ],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  9), 0.6 ]                
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Defaulty shared parameter works between series, not points in the same serie. So you can use [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and loops to find points with the same x.

```
 tooltip: {
        formatter:function(){
            var x = this.x,
                series = this.series,
                txt = '<b>'+series.name+'</b><br>';

            $.each(series.data, function(i,p){
                if(p.x === x) {
                    txt += Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b',p.x) + ': ' + p.y + ' m <br/>'; 
                }
            });

            return txt;


        },
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lod5jsz8/4/

Comment: Good approach. However, in my case each point should have its own tooltip. Displaying all values in the same tooltip is not an option.

Comment: With spline that is not possible, but with line chart, yes. You need to use scatter serie and set lineWidth as 2.

Answer (score 0):

The only good solution I have found so far is to add 1ms to one of the dates. In this case the line seems almost vertical on the chart and a separate tooltip is displayed for each point.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lod5jsz8/6/

```
[Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.8 ],
[Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2) + 1, 0.2 ],
```